# How to set up passwordless login for SSH with different usernames?

Tags: ssh, windows-10, nas, synology

I have a Windows 10 system and use the username "WindowsGod". Funny. :-)
And I have a Synology NAS named "MyDisk" that uses Linux as operating system but my user name for this is "DiskMaster".
I have SSH properly installed as far as I know and I've been trying various solutions to execute the command '`ssh diskmaster@mydisk`' and I hope I would not have to log in. This fails...
So I have created a public and private key and have an '~/.ssh/authorized_keys' for the user diskmaster and I was hoping this would be enough.And it's not as it keeps asking me for that password. And I suspect it has something to do with the different user names...
Am I right?

Anyways, to view a full debug overview:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "mydisk" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to mydisk [fe80::211:32ff:fee1:7262%3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub     error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to mydisk:22 as 'diskmaster'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in fileC:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from mydisk
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:wkeoHiapgWG2GUEcQKZ5UJjLOg9INYhfvU1EM9U2ibM
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from mydisk
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from fe80::211:32ff:fee1:7262%3
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/windo/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host 'mydisk' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error:     2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or     directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:mHcwYJa38rVbir+7Jfa4/qes0Vzwh0CPs7OVdIoUIY4
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
**debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:mHcwYJa38rVbir+7Jfa4/qes0Vzwh0CPs7OVdIoUIY4**
debug3: **send packet: type 50**
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: **receive packet: type 51**
**debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password**
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
diskmaster@mydisk's password:
```

This is way too much information with lots of failures. But I do notice `debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\windo/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256`which suggest it finds the right private key to use. Packet type 50 is sent, type 51 is returned.
What is weird is that the file mentioned contains a private key but SSH seems to think it's a public key? Weird...

Comment: The private key belongs on the client, or in this case, your Windows system.

Comment: Private key is on Windows...

Comment: The _keys_ are private and public, but the generic type of scheme is called [Public Key Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) or Asymmetric but not Private or Public-Private or Private-Public. And thus so is the SSH method and packet; see [RFC 4252 section 7](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4252#section-7)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. Perhaps an issue of case sensitivity? You mention "DiskMaster" and "diskmaster". If the Synology is any kind of *nix then usernames will definitely be case sensitive.

Check the authorized_keys file if you used cut and paste, like I did recently, to ensure there aren't any unwanted line breaks in the newly added key listing.

You can check logs on the Synology to gain more insight into the source of the login prompt. You may need to enable logging in sshd_config usually located in /etc or /etc/ssh.

Also consider file permissions on the remote authorized keys. Have you added the remote to the list of known hosts? (You would be rompted prior to login to do this).

Finally, make sure the remote resolves the hostname of the source address such that it matches the hostne in the authorized_keys file.

Comment: I've been *NIXing since 1984 so I'm used to user/lowercase troubles. :) Everything works, except it keeps asking for a password. Once I provide the password, I'm connected. I don't want this password!

Comment: Other steps have also been taken. Tried ssh with the -v parameter and tried a different key. Tried renaming the private key. Saw a known_host file appear so that's okay. So I seem to do the right things, yet it keeps asking for a password. I'm missing something...

Comment: We are definitely missing some annoying detail. :) Might be helpful to run truss on sshd when you attempt login to determine if there is a problem with permissions, with not looking for authorized_keys, etc. Maybe authorized keys is disabled in sshd config?

Comment: I checked the sshd config and it's enabled.

Comment: Specifically the authorized_keys file, and its containing directory(s) (normally $HOME/.ssh), **must be owned by the specified userid and not allow write access to anyone else (group or other)**.

Answer (score 1):

Having different usernames should not matter if you are already specifying the remote username on the SSH command. The default would have been your local username.

However you need to generate a key pair for your local user and copy over the public key to the the appropriate .ssh/authorized_keys file in the remote user home directory.
Also, you have to make sure you did not specify a password when generating the Key pair.

You can actually specify the private key manually in case it's not stored in the expected location. This may vary based on ssh client software.

```
ssh -vvv -i path/myPrivate.key diskmaster@mydisk
```

use -vvv only to see debug messages to help troubleshoot.

I suspect that the key-based authentication is failing and it's falling back to password method. Good luck troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, the key-based validation fails and falls back to the password. And I've done the things you've mentioned already yet it still solves nothing.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot or log of the debug message you got when you used the -vvv option. Also your audit logs on the server